# What is this category of transform called?

Tags: javascript, math, real-time, transformation, distribution

This is a math question - but really I'm looking for some vocabulary to help me google what I'm trying to do here.   God bless you if you manage to read this and understand what I'm talking about.

I have some javascript code that looks at the frequency data from a song as it is playing and turns the data into 2 numbers. These numbers change several times per second depending on what is going on in the song.

One number (upperAvgFr) represents the 'loudness' of the values coming from the average upper frequencies, and the other (lowerAvgFr) represents the loudness coming from the average lower frequencies.  I modulate these values so they stay between 0 and 1.

I'm then taking these 2 numbers and translating them into visual movement on a 3d object (the objects are just glowing squares simple squares with some symbols on them).  I make them 'pulse' - growing larger and smaller or spinning, changing color - based on the values of the upper frequency and lower frequency number.

So... all that said, I'm finding myself wanting to know some math tricks to play with the distribution.

If I use the upperAvgFr as a multiplier on the height and width of the graphical pulsing square - it would be very small when the value is close to 0, and full size when it is close to 1.

My question is, what are these type of functions called (and where are they found) that can redistribute or transform the values in these distributions so that it is not as even anymore.

Maybe the higher values all get closer to 1, and the lower values stay the same. All of them may be "nudged up" a small amount, but less for the lower numbers, and more for the higher numbers.
That would be one instance of a transform that might be useful, another instance might do the same thing in the opposite direction, or pull them all closer to the middle, etc.

Best example that I can find that is "kinda" like what I want are easing functions where things accelerate and move in non-linear ways: https://konvajs.org/docs/tweens/All_Easings.html

What kind of function am I describing here?  Where can I find libraries of these functions? I imagine they could come in handy with tweening and easing.  I imagine there are some that give "pleasant" feeling distributions.  Some might be "choppier". or "bouncier." What words am I looking for her?

Comment: *I modulate these values so they stay between 0 and 1.* This is often called **normalizing**. Perhaps you’ll have better luck searching for ways to manipulate a normalized distribution? Other words that come to mind are **smoothing** (curving a jagged set), [**attack**](https://www.sweetwater.com/insync/attack/), **biasing**, or **weighting**.